# VSCode CMakeTools debugger: specify different setup for some targets

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I like the built in debugger setup of CMakeTools that lets you debug individual targets. However, I have the simple problem that the main app will require a config file whereas the  test targets require none. Can I somehow specify the debug configuration for each target seperately?

I found [this](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/debugging.html) official man page of CMakeTools very helpful yet it doesn't go into detail about how I would accomplish above goal.

Answer (score 0):

Note that [the documentation being linked to in the question post](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/debugging.html) is not the most up to date. See instead [the debug-launch doc on the CMake Tools GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/debug-launch.md).

If you need to have different arguments / environments for different targets (or even to specify arguments at all), you'll just need to [use launch configs](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/debug-launch.md#debug-using-a-launchjson-file) for each kind.

Comment: So you would configure a launch.json entry for every target?

Comment: @glades I said "kind"- not "target". If some of your targets can share/reuse a launch config, then do that. See also the [command substitution docs](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#command-substitution)